# Sort asp:gridview which is bounded to class which instances contain some null objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have bounded a list of object to asp:gridview. Objects in this list contain some properties and some objects. Some objects inside the objects of list are null. I have set sort expression on my gridview boundfields, but i get exception of instance not set to object while sorting. How to sort it correctly? I mean how to avoid accessing null objects in sorting?

```
class A
{
   int value {get; set;}
   string name {get; set;}
   B insideobj;
}

class B
{
}
```

I try to sort list of A objects, one column is sorted by property inside B object, but sometimes B object is null in A object and when it is null than default sorting with using the sort expression throw error.

Comment: Do you use C# or VB.NET? Can you post a sample of your classes and describe which objects are null?

Comment: I use C#. Example code added.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid problems when sorting a `List<A>` by the properties of the type `B` is to not have null references in the `insideobj` member of `A`. You can use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and assign an instance of the null object to items in the list that do not have a value in the member. This way, null references are not a problem anymore when sorting.

The null object is either an instance of `B` with neutral properties (e.g. `string.Empty` instead of null) or is derived from `B` in order to share the same signature.

Sample:

```
class B
{
   public string PropertyToSortBy { get; set; }

   // Provides the Null object
   public static B Empty
   {
       get
       {
           // Initialize other properties as required
           return new B() { .PropertyToSortBy = string.Empty };
       }
   }
}
```

In order to use the Null object, you can change `A` to initialize the value of `insideobj`:

```
class A
{
   int value {get; set;}
   string name {get; set;}
   B insideobj = B.Empty;
}
```

Alternatively, you change the list before sorting like this:

```
var list = new List<A>();
// Fill list
// ...
// Fill empty entries
foreach(var item in list.Where(x => x.insideobj == null))
    item.insideobj = B.Empty;
// Continue using the list
```

Comment: Thank you, i already solved my problem by setting sort expression to empty, and implement my own sorting function for case of that one column. Your solution will also work, but my problem was that i used class library which i didnt have access to, and it returned sometimes null reference objects. Anyway, thanks for help!